# Does LinkedIn provide an API for offline access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, linkedin-api

I am working on a a rails project based on social media networks. Is there any sort of offline access available for LinkedIn? That is, I am creating a application where I need to post links to the user's LinkedIn wall even when the user is offline. Can anyone guide me in this with an sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store the access token that a user generates when they authorize your application and then use it to create your posts/shares when users are not logged in